# How do i load a compiled Java class in JRuby?

Tags: java, jruby

So, I've started out with Java and having some trouble loading a class in a JRuby script, or in another Java app. Let's use this file as an example:

```
package dice;
import java.util.Random;
public class Dice {
    public int sides;
    private Random random;
    public Dice(int sides) {
        this.sides = sides;
        this.random = new Random();
    }
    public Dice() {
        this.sides = 6;
        this.random = new Random();
    }
}
```

When i compile it in NetBeans, it makes a jar file with that class file in it, and a META-INF file. I can require it in JRuby, but i can't do the java_import part:

```
irb(main):013:0> java.dice.Dice
Traceback (most recent call last):
        7: from C:/jruby-9.2.4.1/bin/jirb:13:in `<main>'
        6: from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1181:in `catch'
        5: from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1181:in `catch'
        4: from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1415:in `loop'
        3: from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1043:in `eval'
        2: from (irb):13:in `evaluate'
        1: from org/jruby/javasupport/JavaPackage.java:252:in `method_missing'
NameError (missing class name (`java.dice.Dice'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still upvoting, but found it out myself, i just need to do

```
Java::dice.Dice
```

because, it only works without the `Java::` part when it is in the java folder of packages like

```
java.lang.System
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of package statement I put dice inside of dir dice, and compiled it.

`.
└── dice
    ├── Dice.class
    └── Dice.java`

Run IRB

`$ irb`

We need to add the classpath to Jruby and import using package prefix

```
jruby-9.2.0.0 :001 > $CLASSPATH << "."

jruby-9.2.0.0 :002 > java_import 'dice.Dice'
 => [Java::Dice::Dice] 

jruby-9.2.0.0 :003 > Dice.new
 => #<Java::Dice::Dice:0x4f9a3314>
```

Comment: Upvoting, but found a better solution. Btw use JIRB for a guaranteed JRuby prompt.